# Understanding Vaadin Flow / Vaadin 10

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

preamble: I'm an advanced Vaadin developer (I've used 6, 7, and now all my project are migrated to Vaadin 8).

I'm starting to study Vaadin 10 / Flow, but I find myself in some hot waters.

What I'm actually struggling with is the "project" itself. 
The more I deep into, the more I feel like this framework is moving into a css / html based framework, which requires more css/html knowledge than java.
What I mean is that if you don't perfectly know how css and html works, you can't use this framework easly anymore.

The problem is that I don't know if I'm totally missing the point here and I'm losing into a glass of water, or if that's if really a totally different framework.
Here is where I'm asking an opinion from you, and some confrontations.

I'm finding some very good stuff like **@Router** and all new navigation paradigms and new Mobile First components, but in example I really can't find a rapid way to build a nice look and feel layout without working with css and html.

Easy stuff done with Vaadin 8 looks now for me very hard to understand... like Templates: working with Vaadin 10 Designer is really, really weird.

I hope I'm simply missing the point, and some of you can help me clearing my thoughts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I share your concerns about [Vaadin Flow](https://vaadin.com/flow). Here are some impressions I have gathered in learning about Vaadin 6-14, studying the doc, reading the forums, watching the [Vaadin Ltd YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/vaadinofficial). While I do not cite technical proof for every point below, this might help you orient to the purpose and new reality of Vaadin Flow.

## Web browsers have matured

[image: Logo for the HTML5 project.]

The years in developing [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) are paying off with huge rewards now.

One of the major goals of the leaders of [WHATWG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHATWG) was to rewrite the specs from the practical viewpoint of programmers trying to actually build real browsers. As a result, the modern browsers have far more behavior in common than ever before, with far less [“quirks”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). Web apps nowadays behave much more predictably across the major browsers.

Also, note that the web browser makers have consolidated in their use of engines. Every major browser has abandoned their own engine to use either Apple WebCore/[WebKit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) or its spin-off [Blink](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine))/[Chromium](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)). Even Microsoft has given up on its own browser engine [*Trident*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_(layout_engine))/[*EdgeHTML*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdgeHTML), and [has switched to Chromium](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/12/06/microsoft-edge-making-the-web-better-through-more-open-source-collaboration/) for their line of *Microsoft Edge* browsers. So [Safari](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_(web_browser)), [Edge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge), [Chrome](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome), [Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_(web_browser)), [Brave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_(web_browser)), [Vivaldi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivaldi_(web_browser)), and so on are all using much the same engine now, for much closer behaviors. Only Mozilla Firefox continues to use its own web browser engine, [Gecko](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_(software)) (except for Firefox for iOS which uses WebKit per Apple policy). So, we are down to two main browser engines: WebKit/Chromium & Gecko.

This means a major burden on the previous versions 6, 7, and 7 of Vaadin, making up for behavior differences between browsers, has greatly eased. Vaadin’s internal design can now work more directly with the web's own [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)/[CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)/[DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) model without having to create it's own intervening layer of behavior.

## CSS

[image: Diagram of concentric circles showing the features of CSS 1, 2, and 3.]

[CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) has improved *radically* in recent years with [CSS3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#CSS_3) finally getting fleshed-out and widely adopted.

For decades the experts said “don’t use HTML `table` for layout” yet offered no page layout in CSS except for the anemic `float` feature. **Finally, CSS 3 offers real layout**, feature-rich and robust. And more amazingly, apparently the browsers have broadly supported these features with very compatible implementations. These new layout technologies are *Flex-box* and *Grid-layout*.

By the way, there will be no “CSS 4”. Each of the functionality areas comprising CSS 3 is now its own project with its own development and versioning. This is explained well in one of the excellent videos by [Jen Simmons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jen_Simmons) on YouTube channel [*LayoutLand*](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7TizprGknbDalbHplROtag) though I cannot locate it at the moment.

### [Flexbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_flex-box_layout)

Arrange items in a 1-dimensional horizontal row or vertical column. Control stretching-shrinking, inbetween-spacing, left-centering-right positioning, and relative aligning including baseline.

See [this excellent visual guide and tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Sound familiar? CSS flex-box provides the same kind of functionality as the Vaadin `HorizontalLayout` and `VerticalLayout` classes. Indeed, in Vaadin Flow those classes have been rebuilt to directly use this CSS functionality rather than recreating that behavior within Vaadin. Vaadin Flow has changed its terminology to match that of the CSS standard, such as `setExpandRatio` becoming `setFlexGrow`.

See what versions of [what browsers support Flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

### [Grid Layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_grid_layout)

Arrange items in a 2-dimensional grid of rows and columns. Features are similar to to arranging data in cells in an HTML table. Contents can be aligned up-down or left-right within the cell. Contents can optionally span across multiple cells. You can control gap-spacing and justification.

See an [excellent tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) by the same CSS-Tricks.com site as mentioned above.

Sound familiar? CSS grid layout provides the same kind of functionality as the `GridLayout` in previous versions of Vaadin. The `GridLayout` class in no longer built for Vaadin Flow, but you can get much the same behavior using a  Vaadin [`Div`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/11.0.2/com/vaadin/flow/component/html/Div.html) object combined with direct CSS commands.

See what versions of [what browsers support CSS Grid](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid).

### Roll-your-own `AbsoluteLayout`

On a related note, CSS now provides for on-the-fly pixel-oriented layout. Again, this seems to be [well-supported across browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=CSS%202.1%20properties) in a consistent matter. So in Vaadin Flow, they decided to drop the [`AbsoluteLayout`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.6.1/com/vaadin/ui/AbsoluteLayout.html)which provided this ability to layout widgets in a x-y coordinate system.

In place of `AbsoluteLayout`, you can make your own simple little layout class by extending the new [`Div`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/11.0.2/com/vaadin/flow/component/html/Div.html) component. In that subclass, for any given widget, you can extract the `Element` object that represents the HTML element for that widget within the rendered web page. With that [`Element`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/11.0.2/com/vaadin/flow/dom/Element.html) in hand, you can specify the left & top (x-y) coordinates to be respected.

CSS can be updated dynamically now, so you can change positioning around, or add/drop widgets, within this layout dynamically during runtime.

For an example of such a CSS layout subclass of `Div`, see [*Replacement for `AbsoluteLayout` from Vaadin 8 Framework in Vaadin 10 Flow?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51216311/642706).

## Web Components

[image: Logo for the WebComponents.org project]

The emerging [Web Components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Components) technologies are a game changer, having replaced [GWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit). They allow web pages, and web apps, to be assembled as a collection of chunks each with their own little world of HTML, CSS, and DOM. This encapsulated scope lets a chunk be added without affecting the rest of the chunks. For example, no namespace collisions in naming of CSS classes and identifiers.

This has meant a huge re-write of the Vaadin internals. And so we must be patient (or just keep using Vaadin 8), as some parts we rely on in previous Vaadin are gradually added to Flow. See the page in the manual on [*Components in Vaadin 10*](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/migration/5-components.html) for a comparison of v8 versus v10/11/12 components. This page has been kept up to date. For example `MenuBar` changed from being unplanned to now being expected in Vaadin 14.

On the downside, some features of previous Vaadin may not appear. But read that page carefully and research. Some parts that Vaadin previously created on its own are now directly represented as now-reliable HTML or CSS features.

## Conclusion

Like you, I have mixed feelings about Vaadin Flow.

The recent talk from Vaadin Ltd about “mobile first” is worrisome. That seems tangential from their legacy of building serious business apps, enterprise-style invoice/purchase-order/accruals kinds of apps, “boring” software as I call it (and make my living from), as opposed to startup-of-the-week web app with severe design and wacky interfaces.

Some parts important for enterprise business apps such as menu bars are currently missing with no good workaround. The Web Components technologies are relatively new in the industry, and will likely have some rough edges and problems in these next few years. The nice safe Vaadin-only bubble I enjoyed is now porous, with app development likely to have some need to involve a bit more CSS or other web tech.

On the other hand, it looks like the enterprise/business features may come, either from within Vaadin or from outside as web-components wrapped as Vaadin objects. The Web Components technologies and their various [polyfills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) are not new, and have been worked on seriously for some years by many people, and seem to be workable now. As for CSS or other web tech leaking into Vaadin, I do not minding learning a bit more about these given how robust and well-designed they are now and how that means much more documentation and stability may come with them, with Vaadin not having to re-create features across squirrelly browsers.

And some of that porousness of CSS/HTML leaking-in may be closed where it makes sense and provides convenience to the Vaadin programmer. For example, I noticed in the [Vaadin-12 Releases](https://vaadin.com/releases/vaadin-12) page, there is a new Java API for choosing an alternative built-in component style from Lumo or Material theme for any of the components that have a variant, along with convenient Java constants defined for naming those variants. Ex: `primaryButton.addThemeVariants( ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY ) ;`. This alleviates the need to access the inner `Element` and manipulate CSS.

I believe in the long run, the future for Vaadin is bright. As a server-side stateful application server able to auto-generate web app clients from (for the most part) non-web programming leaves it as an amazing tool in a position with no direct competition (save [Xojo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xojo) Web Edition, using a similar architecture).

## Resources

- [*Should you upgrade to Vaadin 14?*](https://vaadin.com/blog/should-you-upgrade-to-vaadin-14-)
  by Marcus Hellberg 2019-08-21 on Vaadin.com blog
- [*V8 vs. V10 - two maintained Vaadin versions, which one to choose?*](https://vaadin.com/blog/should-you-upgrade-to-vaadin-14-)
  by Matti Tahvonen 2018-06-13 on Vaadin.com blog

Comment: I'm just sorry I can only give you only 1 upvote. This is exactly the kind of answer I was waiting for. I'm gonna study deeper all your links and examples, then I'll feedback. Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 4):

Vaadin 10 keeps the same philosophy of previous versions: Implement the UI with Java. No need to use HTML or JavaScript at all. Vaadin 10 added some support for HTML templates, but it's an optional feature.

This video can help you to understand Vaadin 10: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Un8zKzw6twM

The Wikipedia page for Vaadin is also useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin

Read the documentation chapter on [migrating from Vaadin 8 to Vaadin 10](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/migration/1-migrating-v8-v10.html).

Comment: Hi Alejandro,
I've watched and studied your video, but what the video is showing is only some "basic" stuff, and in fact I've fully reproduced your demo by myself without any problem.

But what about if I try, for example, to build some advanced stuff with designer?
Whit vaadin 8 I can't do anything with that, with 10 I can't do nothing with designer, because everything need css/html knowledge... do you agree or I'm wrong?

Comment: Hi. Yeah, the UI in the video is pretty simple, but you can extrapolate to more complex UIs using the same approach (coding Java). I'd say you don't need much knowledge about HTML and CSS with Designer. You can use the D&D functionality without knowing much about HTML and get fairly advanced UIs done. I'm still curious about the reason you think Vaadin "requires more css/html knowledge than java". From which example/code/video/doc/starter/webpage did you get this impression?

Comment: I've tried to dig deeper into V10 at first with starter "project base", and that's was all clear. Then I tried "simple UI app", and that's where my confusion started. The reviewList class for example is full of not so clear (imho, obviously) mechanisms and fully based on a CSS layouting. From there I've supposed that's is the only way to build forms with designer. And also I saw that I can't anymore set styles on components like before, ie:  btnAccept.setStyleName(Theme.button_friendly)

Comment: The Lumo theme still has varieties of some of the web components, for example [the button](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-button/html-examples/button-lumo-theme-demos).

You can set the theme from Java using something like `button.getElement().setAttribute("theme", "contrast primary");`. There's been some discussion about creating constants for this, like Lumo.CONTRAST, but I'm not sure about the current state of that.

Comment: @Tazavoo, this is available in Vaadin 12+. Example: `button.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY, ButtonVariant.LUMO_CONTRAST);`.